# Getting the result from a fetch function in javascript

Tags: javascript, http, fetch-api

I'm struggling to get the actual result data from an http fetch in js. I can do it using XMLHttpRequest, but I'd much rather use fetching. I've been trying to get the results from a fetch request like this: `fetch('https://api.website.net/?);`

I know that you need to assign a then function but nothing I have tried has worked I keep getting more promise objects and no results. I understand vaguely that you need to assign a .then function for once it resolves but I really cannot figure out how to do that.

(This is in browser js not node)

Comment: There are thousands (millions?) of examples of promises generally and fetch specifically, without a [mre] it's hard to say what your specific problem is. If you're in a non-browser environment you will need to polyfill fetch.

Comment: lol oh come on really? you can find multiple tutorials on promise and fetch. It is better the read about promise in javascript than to just get a simple answer to your question

Answer (score 11):

I think that you're getting confused with promises. The fetch function returns a promise and not the data.

I recommend that you read this modern tutorial: https://javascript.info/fetch

This is a very trivial function that gets the url and returns the response data in json:

```js
async function callApi(url) {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const data = await response.json();

  return data;
}

let data = await callApi('https://api.website.net/?');
// do whatever you want with the data
```

When dealing with primises there are 2 syntaxes, the old `.then()` and the new `async`/`await`. **Using `async`/`await` is better**, in general, so I recommend using the `async`/`await` syntax. With `.then()` it would look like this:

```js
// Not recommended alternative

fetch('https://api.website.net/?')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    // do whatever you want with the data
  });
```

Comment: Your second part of the post is misleading. `async/await` is just a sugarcoat around original promises. `.then` is part of the original promise' synthax.

Comment: Why is the second not recommended? It works very well and is much easier to understand

Comment: When you want to split the async calls into functions, the new syntax is way clearer. When looking at just a fetch if may seem simpler, but when handling multiple promises or having many functions async/await shines. I personally prefer less indentation, that's another benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
fetch(....)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => /* use data */);
```

Comment: you still have to wait for the promise to complete.